# SQL Server - Insert with multiple sub queries (3 tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `BankHoliday` which contains a `Date` field along with the `Id` field.. This currently has all of the dates for this year's and next year's Bank Holidays.

I also have a table called Staff which contains `StaffID`, `StaffName`, `Active`

Now using SQL I am trying to write an insert statement into a table called `Calendar` in which these Bank Holiday Dates are inserted. This table contains `CalendarDate`, `CalendarID` and `StaffID`,

The `StaffID`  is where my problem is...

**The Question**

How can I write an INSERT statement in SQL Server where it will fetch a list of the `Active` Staff Members along with each individual Bank Holiday `Date`, and then INSERT them into the `Calendar` table?

**Example Data** would return:

```
CalendarID  CalendarDate    StaffID
     1       31/08/2015        1
     2       31/08/2015        2
     3       31/08/2015        3
     4       31/08/2015        4
     5       31/08/2015        5
     6       25/12/2015        1
     7       25/12/2015        2
     8       25/12/2015        3
     9       25/12/2015        4
     10      25/12/2015        5
```

So to clarify the `CalendarDate` above will contain a list of BankHoliday `Date`s that are not currently in this table (`WHERE NOT EXISITS`)

The `StaffID` is retrieved from the `Staff` table where a list contains only `Active` members

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a CROSS JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO Calendar 
SELECT  b.CalendarDate, s.StaffID FROM BankHoliday b
CROSS JOIN Staff s
WHERE s.Active = 1
```

This will get a row for every bank holiday and every active staff member.

Comment: perfect thankyou, I shall look into CROSS JOINS, never used this before but looks very useful

Comment: Cross joins are very rarely used, but it works well in this scenario!

Answer (score 1):

Ther is an accepted answer already, so I'm to late - never mind. Just one hint: I think you could improve the design:

1. You should create a date-table not only for bank holidays, but a
   running list of all dates. These dates you can mark as
   "IsBankHoliday". Such a date list is very usefull in many cases.
2. I don't know what you are going to do with this, but normally you
   would not write data into a physical table, which you can retrieve
   that easily. So - probably! - it's not the  best idea to  do this...

Just my solution to show you the connection of the tables. In fact this is nothing else then the other solution with CROSS JOIN... Person4 is not active, therefore is missing:

```
declare @bankholidays TABLE(ID INT,TheDate DATE);
insert into @bankholidays values(1,{ts'2015-08-31 00:00:00'}),(2,{ts'2015-12-25 00:00:00'});

declare @staff TABLE(StaffID INT,StaffName VARCHAR(100could),Active BIT);
insert into @staff VALUES(1,'Person1',1),(2,'Person2',1),(3,'Person3',1),(4,'Person4',0),(5,'Person5',1);

declare @target TABLE(targetID INT,CalendarID INT,CalendarDate DATE,StaffID INT);

INSERT INTO @target
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bh.TheDate,s.StaffID)
      ,bh.ID
      ,bh.TheDate
      ,s.StaffID
FROM @staff AS s,@bankholidays AS bh
WHERE s.Active=1;

SELECT * FROM @target
```

Comment: thankyou for your advice, it makes more sense storing everything in one table, I shall probably do this so thanks for the advice